# Issue with openxlsx package in R removing data groupings

Tags: r, excel, rstudio, openxlsx

I am using the Openxlsx package to open an existing Excel file, delete and recreate a tab with new, fresh data. On another sheet in the workbook I have some rows grouped together throughout the sheet using the Group section on the Data tab. When I run my script, everything works perfectly except for some reason the Grouping on the sheet not being used is being removed. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `openxlsx::groupColumns(wb, sheet, cols)`

Comment: Avoid answering a question in a way that ask a question... Please rephase it like "This might work for you: <code>" or "Maybe try : <code>". (The current answer triggered a "not an answer" bot because it looks like a question)